# Updating array of objects with useState react hook

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm working on a simple project using react hooks, I want to update the state from fetched data from the api http://geoplugin.net/json.gp. However, when I try to update the state it's not working. Only the initial state is returned.

```
 import React, { Fragment,useState,useEffect } from 'react';
 import {container,Row,Table} from 'reactstrap';
 import axios from 'axios';

function LiveVisitors() {
 const [visitors,setVisitors] =useState([{
     ip: '',
             countryCode: '',
             city: '',
             state: '',
             country: ''
 }]);
const {ip,countryCode,city,state,country} = visitors;

 useEffect(()=>{
     getUserData()
 },[])
 //get user data
 const getUserData = () =>{

 const  res=  axios.get(`http://geoplugin.net/json.gp`).then(res =>{
    // console.log(res)
     const {geoplugin_request,
                     geoplugin_countryCode,
                     geoplugin_countryName,
                     geoplugin_city,
                     geoplugin_region
     
                 } =res.data;
     const visitor = {
         ip: geoplugin_request,
         countryCode: geoplugin_countryCode,
         city: geoplugin_city,
         state: geoplugin_region,
         country: geoplugin_countryName
                 };
     setVisitors(visitors => [...visitors,visitor])
     console.log(res.data)
     console.log({visitor})
     console.log(visitors)
 }).catch (err =>{
     console.log(err)
 })  
     
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works when you remove the axios part that is breaking the setState. I prepared an example for you that works and adds another visitor element.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-hqswi?file=/index.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function LiveVisitors() {
  const [visitors, setVisitors] = useState([
    {
      ip: "",
      countryCode: "",
      city: "Warsaw",
      state: "",
      country: "Poland"
    },
    {
      ip: "",
      countryCode: "",
      city: "Gdańsk",
      state: "",
      country: "Poland"
    }
  ]);
  const { ip, countryCode, city, state, country } = visitors;

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, []);

  const getUserData = () => {
    //imitate fetch
    setVisitors([
      ...visitors,
      {
    ip: "",
    countryCode: "",
    city: "Wrocław",
    state: "",
    country: "Poland"
      }
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {visitors.map((el) => (
    <div>{el.city}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const wrapper = document.getElementById("container");
ReactDOM.render(<LiveVisitors />, wrapper);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I must use the axios call to access the updating data

Comment: Yes I understand. This is what I mean. You define const res = axios..... and then you try to use it somwhere else. Try removing this part 'const  res=' in your call and post the console log of your res.

Answer (score 0):

By using `useEffect` with an empty array at the end you force it to run only once

Try

```js
useEffect(()=>{
     getUserData()
},[visitors]);
```

or without the array

```js
useEffect(()=>{
     getUserData()
});
```

it should trigger every time React detects a change, hope that helps.

Here is a really good [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/lifecycle-methods-with-the-useeffect-hook/) that gives a good explanation.

Comment: Yeah, and it will cause an infinite loop. The issue here is probably with res variable being overwritten.